# Young Adult novel - Aliens with triangular cinnabar eyes rule the Earth

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm almost certain I read this in the summer of 1980, though it may have been the summer before that. It was a paperback, probably young adult but could be adult, and I think most of the artwork on the cover was in green tones. I also remember it as being a stand-alone novel, not part of a series.

In the story, aliens have ruled the earth for a long time. I want to say the aliens have made the Earth park-like and some characters ride horses, however, it may just be the elite alien's estate that is park-like? In their natural form, the aliens are 6-fingered humanoids, but the ones stationed on Earth go through a transformative process that makes them look almost completely human. The only thing they can't change is their eyes, which are triangular and cinnabar colored.

They've ruled here for long enough that the main character (male) has been raised since childhood (maybe birth?) in their service, and has never left earth. He's extremely loyal and has some special status that causes him to become the student of an elite alien? However, things have reached a point where the aliens decide to abandon Earth. (Human uprising I think?) For some reason, the alien protected by the main character stays behind, and they both end up on the run. I want to say the alien was female, is definitely high ranking, and stays behind because only an alien could operate the transport or the transformation machine or something for the rest? I think the destination they are trying to reach is some special location (on Earth) where technology exists to send her home, and that they succeed.

The only other detail I can remember is that the last alien has a bunch of zoo animals released before they go on the run because the societal collapse that will follow the alien abandonment of Earth means the animals won't be cared for anymore.

Later edit: As noted in the comments this seems to match many of the elements asked about by @Lorendiac ["Old SF novel about a white-haired young woman, alien or half-alien, who tutors human kids"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160352/old-sf-novel-about-a-white-haired-young-woman-alien-or-half-alien-who-tutors-h/160432) In addition to what I've mentioned above, these details also match up:

1. The book was on loan to my local library from the local middle or high school library, and so was probably not aimed at full adults. (However, I was already testing at a grade 10 reading level when I was in the 4th grade, so my idea of what constitutes "young adult reading level" may have been seriously skewed!)
2. The alien is tutoring 2 humans, 1 male & 1 female, who I remember as being in their late teens or early 20's. In my memory, the male student is the POV character, but it could have been the alien teacher.
3. The alien has an unusual, but still human, hair color. Most likely white or silvery-white. After they go on the run she keeps it covered and wears sunglasses to pass as human. At a key point in the story, her hair is seen by an enemy but another character manages to bluff their way out of it. (Or almost does?)

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. This [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) may be of use to you in jogging your memory for more details.

Comment: You're sure it was around 1980? Couldn't have been as late as 1987?

Comment: No. I read it the summer between elementary & middle school, so it couldn't have been published later than 1980.

Comment: Gordon Dickson's *Way of the Pilgrim* is not the book you're looking for, but it has some interesting similarities. Earth is ruled by alien conquerors; the main character is a loyal servant of the head alien; in the end the aliens abandon Earth.

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Knight-Ghosts-Shadows-Flandry-Book-ebook/dp/B005HRT6P6/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1515237224&sr=8-1&keywords=knight+of+ghost+and+shadows has mention of cinnabar eyes and six-fingered aliens.

Comment: Darn, that's not it. The aliens lose the 6th finger when they're transformed, and the main character hasn't ever been off of Earth. I don't think it was part of a series either, though I may be wrong. I'll edit to add that detail.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but this question by @Lorendiac, ["Old SF novel about a white-haired young woman, alien or half-alien, who tutors human kids"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160352/old-sf-novel-about-a-white-haired-young-woman-alien-or-half-alien-who-tutors-h/160432) might refer to the same book. I thought that Lorendiac might be conflating two different works. The parts of their description that I *didn't* recognize sound like your book. Aliens with funny eyes ruling Earth, a loyal human servant, deurbanized landscape, and the cover is mostly green.

Comment: @user14111, I agree that *The Way of the Pilgrim* does have some similarities with the OP's question but isn't the the book they are seeking. However the main human character of Dickson's book is *anything but* a loyal servant of the head alien.The nearest he gets to that is that he does end up having some sympathy with his alien master..

Comment: @Lostinfrance I think you're right! Much of what they described sounds like the right book mixed in with some other book I haven't read. I'd forgotten there was a young female human too, and about the alien being their teacher, but in hindsight, I'm certain that's correct, though I think the alien teacher is also some kind of VIP? The alien covering her white hair and wearing sunglasses matches my memory too. And I could easily be scrambling the male student together with the male bodyguard mentioned. I'll look over the details and add the matching bits to my question.

Comment: @Lostinfrance You're right. "Loyal" was a typo for "trusted" which is quite different.

Comment: FWIW I have Under Alien Stars and there are some serious mismatches. The alien (Tsorian) girl has completely black eyes with no iris and she doesn't wear sunglasses to hide them. The Tsorians have three fingers not six, and there is no mention of riding horses.

Comment: @JohnRennie, the point of [my answer to Lorendiac's earlier question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160352/old-sf-novel-about-a-white-haired-young-woman-alien-or-half-alien-who-tutors-h/160432#160432) was that it seemed to me that Lorendiac might be mixing up two books. Some parts of their recollections seemed close to  *Under Alien Stars*, which I also have, but they also supplied detailed memories that clearly did not relate to *UAS*, e.g. the loyal human servant. It was the parts of Lorendiac's recollections that were *not* like *UAS* that corresponded to Jumanji's question.

Comment: ...or, of course, it might turn out that the similarities between the book that both Jumanji and Lorendiac are looking for and *Under Alien Stars* were purely coincidental. I really want that book to be found now, it sounds interesting.