# SciFi book about two alien races fighting over Earth

Tags: story-identification, alien-invasion

I read the book about twenty years ago and I don't really think it was new. I think it was kind of a young adult type book. Basically there's a race of humanoid aliens who have occupied Earth. The main character is a young boy who doesn't like the aliens. Then there is a young female alien who I think was the daughter of the higher ups for the aliens. They end up having to work together when another, more malicious alien race shows up. I remember there being a description of the evil aliens in the book as having bodies like a jackknife. I know that's not much to go on but it's been bugging me for a long time.

Comment: The sexes are the other way round, otherwise they *could* be the human Easy Rich and the Drommian Aminadorneldo in meeting the Tenebrites in Hal Clement's *Close to Critical*.

Comment: No that's not it. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't sound like William Tenn's short story "The Liberation of Earth" is what you are looking for but it matches the title pretty well and is a much overlooked masterpiece.

Comment: No it was definitely a novel. I wish I could provide more info about it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The mention of the "evil aliens" as "having bodies like a jackknife" makes me confident that the book is *Under Alien Stars* by Pamela F. Service. I answered an earlier question seeking this book and mentioning "aliens that resemble Swiss Army knives" [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126428/earth-occupation-invasion-book-i-read-in-the-90s/127857#127857). All the other plot elements match that novel too. I know the correct procedure for this Stack Exchange would be to close this question and mark it as a duplicate while linking to the earlier answer, but I don't know how.

Comment: @Lostinfrance It takes 3000 rep to participate in close/re-open voting, and we only make duplicates once the OP agrees that the linked question IDs the right story. So we're waiting on Jeremy at this point.

Comment: Yes that's it!  Thank you so much!